Laravel breeze translation issue: forgot-password.blade.php custom translations not working
I have custom translation files

lang/en/passwords.php
lang/de/passwords.php

with
return [
    'reset' => 'Your password has been reset.',
    'sent' => 'We have emailed your password reset link.',
    'throttled' => 'Please wait before retrying.',
    'token' => 'This password reset token is invalid.',
    'user' => "If a user with that email address exists, you will receive a password reset email.",
];

and equivalent in de.
My forgot-password.blade.php uses
if ($status != Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
        $this->addError('email', __($status));

        return;
}

On passwords.user for example it always returns the error string defined in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/lang/en/passwords.php instead of my custom one.
However if I rename passwords.user to passwords.User and do the same in my custom translation file, the custom translation is returned.
Please advice what I am doing wrong...cleared cache etc, changed session locale, nothing worked except renaming translation keys which is in my opinion a dirty workaround.
Thanks

in config.php, what is your locale ?

@francisco     'locale' => 'de',
'fallback_locale' => 'en',

ok, do php artisan cache:clear php artisan config:clear php artisan view:clear php artisan route:clear php artisan optimize:clear, and check.  Change the fallback  to de, and then check. you can try to set the local to app()->setLocale('de');, and check if it changes...

@francisco thanks, I did everything on local and staging, nothing worked. It's still using the laravel translations for auth errors.

I am sorry...i finally sorted out the problem...
I am using Filament with the Plugin https://filamentphp.com/plugins/filament-spatie-translatable
This overrides all the lang files except the en.json / de.json even for non filament pages.
